# How to display an image using UIView in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimageview, xcode4.2

Absolutely beginner question. I am trying to make an app which will switch an array of images by swiping the screen sideways. So, as vanilla case of that I was trying to display an image first and then think about how to switch between images using an action. I am using XCode 4.2.

So, here's what I have so far. I have added a UIImageView to my storyboard, then Ctrl+dragged into the ".h" file to create an Outlet and it looks something like this:

#### SwitchViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;


@end
```

And then in the ".m" file, I am trying to set an image to the UIImageView in the DidLoad method.

#### SwitchViewController.m

```
#import "SwitchViewController.h"

@implementation SwitchViewController
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImage *plate1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plates1.tif"];
    [imageView setImage:plate1];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImageView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||

        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))

        return YES;



    return NO;
}

@end
```

Now, if I try to run this, there are no compilation errors. 
But the program halts saying, *Thread 1:Program received signal "SIGABRT"*

Comment: Probably an exception being thrown. Can you show us the output on the console in Xcode please?

Comment: Is the IBOutlet connected to the `UIImageView` in the .xib?
Also you should use `[self.imageView setImage:plate1];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mattjgalloway. The console is going something like this. 

2012-01-26 22:04:40.728 Switch-a-Switch[548:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SwitchViewController 0x6840660> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key UIImageView.'

Comment: @basvk: Thanks. I did drag the Outlet from the storyboard to the interface. I'm sorry but I am extremely new to XCode and Objective C. I can see a .storyboard file but I cannot find an .xib file. I changed *[imageView.setImage:plate1]* to *[self.imageView.setImage:plate1]*.

Comment: @AshinMandal See my answer - you're trying to set to the key called `UIImageView`. You must have gotten the link wrong in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your actual problem, you're getting this exception being thrown:

```
2012-01-26 22:04:40.728 Switch-a-Switch[548:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SwitchViewController 0x6840660> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key UIImageView.'
```

It would appear that you've wired up the `UIImageView` to a property called `UIImageView` rather than `imageView`. Go and redo the connection in Interface Builder and make sure you drag from the `imageView` property to your `UIImageView` instance.

Comment: From the properties tab, I dragged the Image View Object from the list of objects. It creates a blue tint rectangle with UIImageView written on it. I drag my Outlet from that rectangle. The literal description is to make sure I am doing the right thing. (:

Comment: Yeh it sounds like you're doing it right, but if you're still getting that exception thrown then you're doing something wrong. You should right click on the File Owner and drag from the circle on the right of `imageView` to your `UIImageView` you dropped on your view.

Comment: Hey. I couldn't find the File Owner. So, what I did was cleaned everything up. Storyboard as well as the controller. Then tried to build once just to check that I don't get the error again. And then added a Image View again, dropped an Outlet and wrote the viewDidLoad method again. And it worked. Thanks a lot! (:

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *plate1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plates1.tif"];
[imageView setImage:plate1];
```

should be kosher in iOS and 64 Bit (non-fragile ABI environments, as the iVar will be synthesized), I think it is much better form to include the ivar in the interface....

```
@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
```

The thing that you should do to track this down is to turn on zombies and enable an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I'm sorry but but all my coding (whatever little I've done) so far has been done in Java. So I create instances of objects and pass them as arguments. Getting used to pointers is taking a little time for me. 

When you say include ivar in the interface, do you mean that I create an interface block in the ".m" file and synthesize it there?

Comment: no sorry iVar, is an instance variable declared in the interface.

Comment: which is done for you behind the scenes in iPhone and 64bit intel runtimes... but you should still specify anyway, at least until you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

afew things there. (now im only learning myself so may be wrong but here goes)

when you use the @property u should use the self.imageView setter to assign to it. so [imageView setImage:plate1] would become self.imageView.image = plate1. and change it from weak to retain in the .h. and in the viewdidunload do self.imageView = nil. also i think the swiping of images effect your trying to achieve here might be better suited to a horizontal scrollview. and u can turn on paging or something for that.
hope that helps and didnt send u completely wrong direction :P

Comment: Do not change it to a retain. Weak is perfectly fine here as you should let the parent UIView retain the ImageView for you. Weak ensures that it will be nil if the parent ever goes away. You don't actually need to set it to nil in the unload because of that.

Comment: There is no need to use 'self' when accessing a property on the imageview, only needed when you are setting the imageview property itself. I.e. [imageView setImage:anImage] is fine, or self.imageView =  anImageView

Comment: @glogic : Thanks. So, I did take your advice changed *[imageView setImage:plate1]* to *self.imageView.image = plate1* but nothing changed. I still get that "SIGABRT" thing and the build halts, iOSSimulator is just black.

Comment: ah yes simon. thats right i wasnt thinking there (+1). i had first set it as self.imageview = plate1 but then seen plate1 was the image not another imageview and did a quick edit adding .image to it. ashin ignore everything i said it was comepletely wrong :P only thing i can see that would stop it from compiling is if the imageView in the storyboard is not attached correctly to the iboutlet in the .h . when u go to storyboard and right click on the uiimageview name that is on the left in the view controller scene list. what name does it say it is attached to? does it say imageView is its name?

Comment: When I right-click on it, it says Referencing Outlets: imageView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way. If you want to side swip to go between images, you should use a UIScrollView with paging enabled. A quick google came up with [this](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/).

Hope that helps

Comment: I do want to switch between images, but not with the swipe animation, I want the images to morph into the next one. There will be two set of pictures one overlapped over the other. And if I swipe horizontal the picture below should change and the one above should switch on vertical swipe. And this swiping can be done anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Ah ok - in that case you will have to look into CoreAnimation. You should be able to change the alpha values, which will make the images 'morph' into each other. You can call the animation by using UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sure. I'll try doing that as soon as I am able to show the image through UIImageView. (: